# Raspberry Pi AP crashes when transferring large files over FTP

Tags: raspbian, access-point, hostapd

I have an Access Point set up on my Raspberry Pi 4 using a wifi dongle and hostapd. Everything works great, but when I start to transfer a file over FTP, the connection aborts at around 1 GB and I have to reconnnect to the AP.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you stay connected indefinitely if you're not using FTP?

Comment: Yes I think so, I just noticed the problem when I transferred a large file via FTP. But I think it happens always, when I need big bandwidth and it looks like there is already a solution for that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar behavior because of weak firmware. Not sure if it also helps in your case but it might be worth a try. You can downgrade the firmware to a more stable version. Have a look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). At the beginning there is a part, labeled *IMPORTANT UPDATE on 2020-09-02*, that described how to downgrade the firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sounds hopeful. I will try it soon and tell you if it worked for me.

Comment: I tried it. But the AP is still crashing on transferring large files. Is there a more stable version?